# How to loop images with react-native-svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a project with react native and we chose to use react-native-svg in order to display our map. Everything's worked perfectly so far, except for this : 
I have an array of objects that each have coordinates and a size. I want to loop through this array to display an image at all of these coordinates. But no luck, I managed to diplay shapes and texts but no images.

Here is the render function of my parent element :

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Svg
          height={screen.height}
          width={screen.width}
        >
          <G
            width={mapSize.x}
            height={mapSize.y}
            x={this.state.center.x}
            y={this.state.center.y}
            originX={mapSize.x / 2}
            originY={mapSize.y / 2}
            rotation={this.state.orientation}
            scale={1}
          >
            <Rect
              width={mapSize.x}
              height={mapSize.y}
              x={0}
              y={0}
              scale={1}
              fill="#0071e9"
            />
            <G
              width={mapSize.x}
              height={mapSize.y}
              x={this.state.cnv.x}
              y={this.state.cnv.y}
              scale={1}
            >
              // this is my child component's tag
              <Islands
                islands={this.state.contentToRender}
                deg={this.state.orientation}
              />
            </G>
          </G>
          <Image
            x={(screen.width / 2) - 50}
            y={-(screen.height / 2) + 94.46}
            width="100"
            height="189.9"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            href={images.bateau}
          />
          </G>
        </Svg>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

here is my child component's render :

```
 render(){
    const that = this
    return(
      this.props.islands.map((c) => {
        return (
            <Image
              key={ c.id }
              x={ c.position.x }
              y={ c.position.y }
              width={ c.size.x }
              height={ c.size.y }
              preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
              rotation={-that.props.deg}
              originX={ c.position.x + (c.size.x / 2) }
              originY={ c.position.y + (c.size.y / 2) }
              href={images.rouge}
            />
        )
      })
    )
 }
```

And finally my images.js file :

```
const images = {
    boussole: require('./img/Boussole.png'),
    aiguille: require('./img/Aiguille.png'),
    bateau: require('./img/Bateau.png'),
    home: require('./img/home.png'),
    cyclop_island: require('./img/ile_cyclope_navig.png'),
    rouge: require('./img/smiley-carre-rouge-simple-face-magnetique.jpg'),
}

export default images
```

I have no issue with any aspect of the Svg component, I can display every image of the images.js file as long as they are not in a loop.

Also, even if the image doesn't display the console shows no error.

Comment: If you're using the `Image tag` from `react-native` then you need to follow these [`props`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#props)

Comment: That's not the case, I'm using the `Image tag` from `react-native-svg`.